# How does bitcoin work from a technical computer science cryptography perspective?

Tags: cryptography

How does the cryptography science behind bitcoins work to make it robust(reliable , scalable).
I am interested in technical explanation with cryptography math and not just conceptual explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good resource to learn how \[technically\] bitcoin works?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/whats-a-good-resource-to-learn-how-technically-bitcoin-works)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Whitepaper by Satoshi Nakamoto: http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf

Comment: The paper is actually pretty cursory.