# find the maximum possible reward for creating a block using

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

I'm new to bitcoin development someone request from me to know the maximum possible reward for creating a block using some address.

My Questions :-
1- Which framework and tools can help to do that ? 
2- Reference for learning ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

Currently the maximum reward for mining a block is 12.5 Bitcoin plus any additional transaction fees in that block. This reward halves every 210,000 blocks. It does not matter which address is used for receiving the reward. See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining#Reward.

For learning references, see [What's a good resource to learn how [technically] bitcoin works?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/whats-a-good-resource-to-learn-how-technically-bitcoin-works/12562#12562)

Answer (score 0):

The miner's reward is the sum of the current block reward (originally 50 BTC, but halving every 210,000 blocks, so it is currently 12.5 BTC), and any transaction fees for the transactions included in the block (variable, depends on the transactions included).

Technically speaking, the maximum possible reward for mining a block would be **the sum of all currently spendable bitcoins**.

This assumes that the mined block includes a transaction(s) which pay every single bitcoin on the network to the miner in transaction fees. So obviously, such a situation is incredibly unlikely! I think it is more useful and interesting to consider a metric such as the *average* value of the block reward + transactions fees, instead of the *maximum*.